# mv command not working in J2EE web application

Tags: jakarta-ee, processbuilder, mv

I was trying to set up a J2EE application. Application is up and running now, but there is one upload process that copies a file from one folder to another.

It gives the error

> Cannot run program "mv": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified

in that process. Given below is the code that does the move:

```
ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder("mv", fileName, targetFile.getAbsolutePath());
Process process = processBuilder.start();
```

Appreciate your help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of 'mv', write /bin/mv
You can get the path from 'which mv'